# Is it possible to dynamically generate jQuery Tools tooltip elements?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

According to the jQuery Tools [documentation](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html), the tooltip element must be placed immediately following the trigger in the HTML. However, I need to apply the tooltip events to a dynamically-generated list of items. Since I don't know beforehand the number of items and the tooltip content for each item is unique, I'll need to generate the tooltip elements dynamically (from JavaScript). As such, I was wondering if there's a way to use the jQuery Tools tooltip without having the tooltip element explicitly coded adjacent to the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize it using a delegated event:

```
$("#content").delegate(".tooltop:not(.jqtooltip)","mouseover",function(){
    $(this).addClass("jqtooltip").tooltip(...);
})
```

assuming of course that #content is an ancestor of all dynamic tooltips.